# Cannot print output on the same line

Tags: python, printing

I want my output to print on one line and there should be gap after the input taken by the use.

```
 i = 1
  x = int(input("enter a number to loop" ))

  while(i<=x):
       print('\n',i, end= " ")
       i += 1
```

for my code, my output is not on the same line. how to have an output printed on one line.

Comment: What programming language is this? Make sure to tag your questions correctly so the people familiar with that language are more likely to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your issue

```
i = 1
x = int(input("enter a number to loop " ))
print("\n")
while(i<=x):
   print(i, end= " ")
   i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
The reason there as a \n in code was I want to give a line gap in my input statement and my output.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You added a \n in your print function ..

```py
i = 1
x = int(input("enter a number to loop\n"))

while(i <= x):
    print(i, end=" ")
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
The reason there as a \n in code was I want to give a line gap in my input statement and my output.
How can I do it?

Comment: add that \n in input() function, I edited the answer check that.